# Wordpress mobil will not scroll

Tags: mobile, infinite-scroll

I am on WordPress 5.3.2 running Twenty Fourteen Child theme.
socalda.org
For some reason if you look at the site on the phone you cannot scroll down anymore. It scrolls down on the computer but not on the phone.

Comment: Note that JS/CSS questions should go on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Your site **is** scrolling, you've just put `position:fixed` on the `html` element so that when you scroll down the HTML element stays in the same place